# sed an remove everything after the first pattern (only in the line)

Tags: bash, sed

let say i have a file such as

```
>Species_Name|KIOOL
AATATATATACACACAAGAGAGGA
>SPECIES_name|KUI
AATTAGAGAGA
>Species_names|POPPO
ATATGAATATA
```

How could I in bash get a new file such as :

```
>Species_Name
AATATATATACACACAAGAGAGGA
>SPECIES_name
AATTAGAGAGA
>Species_names
ATATGAATATA
```

I tried `sed 's@|*@@'g my file` but it does not work

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`|*` matches zero or more vertical bars.  You appear to want to match one vertical bar followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters.  Try:

```
$ sed 's/|[[:alnum:]]*//' file
>Species_Name
AATATATATACACACAAGAGAGGA
>SPECIES_name
AATTAGAGAGA
>Species_names
ATATGAATATA
```

In the revised question, it appears that you might want to remove everything after the first vertical bar.  In that case, replace `[[:alnum:]]` with `.` since `.` matches anything:

```
$ sed 's/|.*//' file
>Species_Name
AATATATATACACACAAGAGAGGA
>SPECIES_name
AATTAGAGAGA
>Species_names
ATATGAATATA
```